# What `to` should be set when deploying contracts?

Tags: contract-deployment, web3.py, web3j

I'm deploying contract using eth_sendTransaction and compiled bytecode.

So for example my transaction is:

```
{
   from: "0x0000123...",
   data: "0x6000...",
   gas: "0x9999",
   gasPrice: "0x9999",
   to: ???? whats here?
}
```

I'm just wondering what should `to` address be set? Are people creating new account address in wallet apps, and deploying contracts to that address? What's the typical protocol here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions that are creating a contract are defined as transactions that don't have a `to` address. You should be able to put undefined/null/your language's equivalent, or not include the parameter at all.

From page 4 of the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf):

> **to**: The 160-bit address of the mesage call's recipient or, for a contract creation transaction, Ø, used here...

Comment: How should I get the deployed contract address? I think eth_sendTransaction returns tx.Hash()

Comment: @kpeteL Once the transaction is mined, you can fetch the transaction's receipt (eth_getTransactionReceipt on RPC, web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt on web3js and similar). For transactions that are creating a contract, the receipt will have a `contractAddress` value, which is the address of the newly created contract

Comment: Ahh, of course! Googling indicates that contract address is derived from sender address + nonce. Just wondering if there's a chance of address collision (new contract address equals someone's wallet address)

Comment: There is no risk of wallet collision